# Keycloak SAML IdP gives invalidFederatedIdentityActionMessage after login

Tags: keycloak, saml, idp

I configured a SAML identity provider in keycloak by importing metadata provided by Microsoft ADFS.

I could see the option of IdP on my client login page for login.

After clicking on that on that button it redirects to external identity provider login page.

After login, I get success with a SAMLResponce. (Checked with SAML tracer).

The page is redirected to IDP redirect URL.

After redirecting page shows me "invalidFederatedIdentityActionMessage"

I saw the docker logs it gives me ---

23:58:09,035 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-181) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_RESPONSE_ERROR, realmId=rak-development, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.0.4, error=invalid_saml_response, reason=invalid_destination

Can you please help what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you find the problem? I'm running into the same thing..

Comment: I am also seeing this ... has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you configure the Identity Provider to 'Validate Signature'. When you turn that switch on, Keycloak validates the SAML response against the text in 'Validating X509 Certificates'. That field should contain a valid certificate from your Identity Provider; in this case the App registration in Microsoft.

Try turning the 'Validate Signature' switch off to see if that removes the error. Then you can debug the certificate value.

Comment: In my case, I already have Validate Signature switched off .. I have tried it with and without that turned on.

Comment: I posted more info here if it helps anyone troubleshoot this: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/KEYCLOAK/issues/KEYCLOAK-15005

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be a misconfiguration of the F5 proxy/firewall. It sent the wrong header "X-Forwarded-Proto: http" instead of "X-Forwarded-Proto: https". Maybe this can help.

Comment: Moving the issue to the redhat forum is not helpful in this thread. If you share the TRACE log here maybe someone can shed some light. I have AWS ALB to EC2s with docker. The ALB terminates ssl. So that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. For me, the issue was that I needed to set the PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true envvar. I had already done that but I typoed the name.

I am using the AWS ALB which sets the X-Forwarded headers. I know those are also needed.